# 2d list contour plot

Tags: physics, chemistry, plotting

I have plotted a ListContour plot with a large set of data i have and most of the points do not seem to have a distinguised colour, i.e, the color function needs to be re-scaled for my data. How can i do that?[image]

```
ListContourPlot[Pes, ContourLabels -> All, PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
ColorFunctionScaling -> False, PlotRange -> {{0, 180}, {6, 11}}, 
ColorFunction -> 
Function[{Enn}, ColorData[{"BlueGreenYellow", {-35, 150}}][Enn]]]
```

Comment: Perhaps `ListContourPlot[Pes, ContourLabels -> All, PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 180}, {6, 11}}, ColorFunction -> "BlueGreenYellow"]`?

Comment: `ColorFunctionScaling -> True` ?

Comment: Both these suggestions are giving me the same graph, with the higher or lower points having the same colour (either blue or white)

Comment: It would be easier with the data, but by setting the range to {-35, 150} in ColorData, the max color (yellow) is reached at 150 and is also assigned to everything above 150.

Comment: The thing is my data is pretty huge and ranges from -27 to 2500.